# Placeholder in "sanic" python

Tags: python, sanic

I've recently been working with the Sanic module in python and I was wondering If there's a way to define placeholders in a url. This is kind of hard to explain but I'm going to try my best.

I want it to be like this kind of. Url: `/account/api/public/account/PlaceholderHere/externalAuths`
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Wouldn't the solution be simply be: have application provide a [standard sanic route](https://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sanic/routing.html) with the placeholder path (and relevant values) and have that return a placeholder result?

Comment: Have you looked at the docs? It is not clear from your question what you mean by placeholder. https://sanicframework.org/guide/basics/routing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<>` around the placeholder in your route decorator:

```py
my_route = Blueprint("my_route")

@my_route.route("/account/api/public/account/<placeholder>/externalAuths", methods=["GET"])
async def get_my_route(request, placeholder):
  print(f"here is my placeholder: {placeholder}")
```

Read about [parameters](https://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/19.3/sanic/routing.html#request-parameters) in the docs.